# StreamAnalytics Query: How can i write query with if and else statement?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I need conditional output in stream analytics,like i have one lookup data table.while data streaming i need to check in lookup table with if data is exists or not. if data is exists then add data in eg.output1 or if data is not exists then add data in eg.output2.

This if statement is more then 4 or 5 times so multiple query is not possible

Comment: You can take a look at [case expression](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns.md#query-example-specify-logic-for-different-casesvalues-case-statements)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CASE statements](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns.md#query-example-specify-logic-for-different-casesvalues-case-statements), sample code from doc and you can modify to meet your needs:

```
    CASE xxx
    WHEN xxx THEN yyy
    ELSE
```

Comment: Yes, i can use case statement in select query. my question is that can i use case statement for multiple output. eg. when case match then store data in output1 or else store data in output2